# Reference for proof of completeness of classical predicate logic in a Hilbert system

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, proof-theory, hilbert-calculus

Many proofs of the completeness of classical logic with respect to some particular Hilbert style atomization of it do not explicitly reference the axioms at hand. The devils must be buried in the details, and I am looking for a proof that shows how each axiom contributes to completeness.

For example, intuitionistic propositional calculus can be axiomatized as classical logic minus the law of excluded middle. Therefore, any completeness proof of (that axiomatic presentation of) classical logic must reference the axiom of the law of excluded middle, else such a proof can’t distinguish between classical logic and intuitionistic logic.

The Henkin style proofs I have seen are rather abstract and don’t reference the specific axiom system at hand.

Can someone please offer a reference that does include the gritty details involving all the axioms?

Comment: See textbooks: Church, Mendelson, Shoenfield, Enderton, Tourlakis.

Comment: "Therefore, any completeness proof of (that axiomatic presentation of) classical logic must reference the axiom of the law of excluded middle..." Not correct: LEM is equivalent to many axioms involving negation.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I think LEM is also equivalent to many nontrivial axiom sets of more than one axiom in the same sense of equivalence as you meant above.  I'm guessing you mean that the axiom A is equivalent in that given an axiom set B, both ({A} union B) and ({LEM} union B) have the same theorems under the same rule(s).